# Interview Prep Words in a Grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, branch, words

I've been doing interview prep questions and this is a question that I've had trouble with as I'm unsure how to implement the solution. So here's the setup. You're given an 8x8 grid of letters and a list of words, and you must return the longest word in the list that can be formed by starting at a letter on the grid and then moving about the grid in the way that a knight would in chess. For example, if you had the list ["word", "string", "test"] and the following grid:

```
Y W E Z T N U W
O P A A C Q G F
T E L Z X C V B
N M M W F R T O
U I O N A S D F
B E J O L Z V C
T B N M Q W E R
T A S G X Z R S
```

Then you would return "test", because this can be formed by starting at the bottom left corner of the grid for 'T', jumping up two and to the right one to get the 'E', jumping down two and right one to get the 'S', and then left two and up one to get the 'T', and none of the other words can be formed on this grid.

I think you'd use a branch and bound algorithm but I'm totally lost on how to set that up. Could anyone help? I'm trying to implement in python.

Note: letters can be repeated in the grid, i.e. you can jump on the same letter as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
for every word in the array, iterate through the matrix to find the first letter then you can use a breath first search (BFS) or a depth first search (DFS) on the first letter's neighbors( in this case it would be the 8 positions a knight can jump to) to see if they match up. you can implement BFS or DFS iteratively using a queue or stack respectively.